# Canvas change image background color but keep it's "effects"

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an image where I need to change it's background color, but keep the "effects" on it (on the image the black dots, white lines etc.)

Here's the orginal image:

[image: orginal image]

I managed to change the color, but also I keep removing those "effects". Preview:

[image]

Here's the **code**:

```js
//let's say I want it to be red

var r = 255;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;


var imgElement = document.getElementById('img');

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = imgElement.width;
canvas.height = imgElement.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(imgElement, 0, 0);

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var data = imageData.data;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    if (data[i + 3] !== 0) {
        data[i] = r;
        data[i + 1] = g;
        data[i + 2] = b;
        data[i + 3] = data[i + 3];
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<img src="foo" id="img" />
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

How to **prevent** that?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/06/realtime-image-tinting-on-html5-canvas/

Comment: @nils I wasn't aware that that is called _tinting_ (I'm not a designer). Can you make an example of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For modern browsers except Internet Explorer, you can use compositing to change the hue of your original image while leaving the saturation & lightness unchanged. This will "recolor" your original image while leaving the contours intact.

[image]

Example code that works in modern browsers *except Internet Explorer*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/M449a.png";
function start(){

  // create an overlay with solid #00d9c6 color
  var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
  var tempctx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width=tempCanvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=tempCanvas.height=img.height;
  tempctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  tempctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
  tempctx.fillStyle='#00d9c6';
  tempctx.fillRect(0,0,tempCanvas.width,tempCanvas.height);

  // 
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;

  // use compositing to change the hue of the original image
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='hue';
  ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0);

  // always clean up: reset compositing to its default
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Since Internet Explorer does not support Blend Compositing, you will have to do it manually.

1. Read the RGBA value of each pixel.
2. Convert that RGBA value to HSL.
3. Shift the hue value (the "H" in HSL) by the difference between your blue hue and your desired green hue.
4. Convert the hue-shifted HSL value to RGBA value.
5. Write the hue-shifted RGBA value back to the pixel.

Here's example code of manually shifting the hue:

Important note: This manual method works by manipulating pixels with `.getImageData`. Therefore you must make sure the original image is hosted on the same domain as the webpage. Otherwise, the canvas will become tainted for security reasons and you will not be able to use `.getImageData`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.onload = start;
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioStanding.png";

function start() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 150, 0);
    // shift blueish colors to greenish colors
    recolorPants(-.33);
}

function recolorPants(colorshift) {

    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(150, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imgData.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        red = data[i + 0];
        green = data[i + 1];
        blue = data[i + 2];
        alpha = data[i + 3];

        // skip transparent/semiTransparent pixels
        if (alpha < 200) {
            continue;
        }

        var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
        var hue = hsl.h * 360;

        // change blueish pixels to the new color
        if (hue > 200 && hue < 300) {
            var newRgb = hslToRgb(hsl.h + colorshift, hsl.s, hsl.l);
            data[i + 0] = newRgb.r;
            data[i + 1] = newRgb.g;
            data[i + 2] = newRgb.b;
            data[i + 3] = 255;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 150, 0);
}


function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
        min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch (max) {
            case r:
                h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
                break;
            case g:
                h = (b - r) / d + 2;
                break;
            case b:
                h = (r - g) / d + 4;
                break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return ({
        h: h,
        s: s,
        l: l,
    });
}


function hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
    var r, g, b;

    if (s == 0) {
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    } else {
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t) {
            if (t < 0) t += 1;
            if (t > 1) t -= 1;
            if (t < 1 / 6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if (t < 1 / 2) return q;
            if (t < 2 / 3) return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
    }

    return ({
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255),
    });
}
```

```html
<p>Example shifting color Hue with .getImageData</p>
<p>(Original: left, Recolored: right)</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have a question - how to implement your code if I have a starting RGB value (for your value "colorshift)? I have a slider where I change the color of the canvas item - so I get the RGB value of that color which i need to implement to the canvas background. So basically I need to insert RGB value to your **recolorPants()** function.

Comment: Think of Hues as colors on the colorwheel. If red is at the top at 0% around the circle then green is at 33% and blue is at 66%. `colorshift` is the amount you want to shift the hue component value of the pixel. To find `colorshift` (1) convert your original blue color to HSL, (2) convert your desired green color to HSL, (3) colorshift = (Hue2-Hue1)/100.

Comment: You could use google for instance: https://gmigdos.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/javascript-convert-rgb-values-to-hsl/

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert each pixel to the LSH colour space (lightness/luminance, hue, saturation). Then you set the Hue to the colour you want and keep the calculated luminance and saturation, then convert back to RGB and set the imageData to the new RGB value.

I have added my own code for conversions. There may be faster versions out there.

```
// returns RGB in an array on 3 numbers 0-255
var lshToRGB = function(ll,ss,hh){ //ll 0-255,ss 0-255, hh 0-360
    var l = ll/255;
    var s = ss/255;
    var hhh = (hh/255)*360;
    var C = (1 - Math.abs(2*l - 1)) * s;
    var X = C*(1 - Math.abs(((hhh / 60)%2) - 1));
    var m = l - C/2;

    if(hhh < 60){
        var r = C;
        var g = X;
        var b = 0;
    }else
    if(hhh < 120){
        var r = X;
        var g = C;
        var b = 0;
    }else
    if(hhh < 180){
        var r = 0;
        var g = C;
        var b = X;
    }else
    if(hhh < 240){
        var r = 0;
        var g = X;
        var b = C;
    }else
    if(hhh < 300){
        var r = X;
        var g = 0;
        var b = C;
    }else{
        var r = C;
        var g = 0;
        var b = X;
    }
    r += m;
    g += m;
    b += m; 
    // is there a need to clamp these ????)
    r = Math.round(Math.min(255,Math.max(0,r*255)));    
    g = Math.round(Math.min(255,Math.max(0,g*255)));    
    b = Math.round(Math.min(255,Math.max(0,b*255)));   

    return [r,g,b];
}
// returns array of 3 numbers 0-255,0-255,0-360
var rgbToLSH = function(rr,gg,bb){ // could do without the conversion from 360 to 255 on hue
    var r,
    g,
    b,
    h,
    s,
    l,
    min,
    max,
    d;
    r = rr / 255;
    g = gg / 255;
    b = bb / 255;
    max = Math.max(r, g, b);
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    l = (max + min) / 2;

    if (max == min) {
        h = 0;
        s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch (max) {
        case r:
            h = (g - b) / d;
            break;
        case g:
            h = 2 + ((b - r) / d);
            break;
        case b:
            h = 4 + ((r - g) / d);
            break;
        }
        h *= 60;
        if (h < 0) {
            h += 360;
        }
        h = Math.round(h);
    }
    return [
        Math.min(Math.round(l*255),255),
        Math.min(Math.round(s*255),255),
        Math.min(Math.round((h/360)*255),255)
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you make an example?